# pass matlab image to open3d three::Image in a mex script

Tags: matlab, pointers, casting, mex

I am trying to load an image in a mex script and cast it to the corresponding format that the Open3D library uses, i.e. `three::Image`. I am using the following code:

```
uint8_t* rgb_image = (uint8_t*) mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
int* dims = (int*) mxGetDimensions(prhs[3]);

int height = dims[0];
int width = dims[2];
int channels = dims[4];
int imsize = height * width;

Image image;
image.PrepareImage(height, width, 3, sizeof(uint8_t)); // parameters: height, width, num_of_channels, bytes_per_channel
memcpy(image.data_.data(), rgb_image, image.data_.size());
```

The above works well when I give a grayscale image and specify `num_of_channels` to 1 but not for 3 channel images as you can notice below:

[image]

Then I tried to create a function where I am manually looping through the raw data and assigning them to the output image

```
    auto image_ptr = std::make_shared<Image>();
    image_ptr->PrepareImage(height, width, channels, sizeof(uint8_t));


    for (int i = 0; i < height * width; i++) {
        uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)(image_ptr->data_.data() + i * channels * sizeof(uint8_t));
        *p++ = *rgb_image++;
    }
```

But now it seems that the color channels are wrongly assigned:

[image]

Any idea how to address this issue. The point is that it seems to be something easy but since my knowledge with C++ and pointers is quite limited I cannot figure it out straight forward.

I found this solution here ([Reading image in matlab in a format acceptable to mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211288/reading-image-in-matlab-in-a-format-acceptable-to-mex)) as well but I am not sure how exactly I can use it. To be honest I am quite of confused.

Comment: I dont know most of that syntax, but in the last loop, you seem to be only looping once per image, i.e. only the first channel, i.e. Red

Comment: I do not think that it is once, if you notice it is a loop through all the raw data in the array that is stored  in `rgb`(each channel information comes after each other). For example in opencv here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392138/1476932 you can see that they pass the continuous information to different Mat's and then they merge but since here I do not have the merging functionality I need to to copy the data manually to the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution was quite straight forward as I was though in first place. It was just playing correctly with the pointers:

```
std::shared_ptr<Image> CreateRGBImageFromMat(uint8_t *mat_image, int width, int height, int channels)
{
    auto open3d_image = std::make_shared<Image>();
    open3d_image->PrepareImage(height, width, channels, sizeof(uint8_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < height * width; i++) {
        uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)(open3d_image->data_.data() + i * channels * sizeof(uint8_t));

        *p++ = *(mat_image + i);
        *p++ = *(mat_image + i + height*width);
        *p++ = *(mat_image + i + height*width*2);
    }
    return open3d_image;
}
```

since the `three::Image` expects the data in contiguous order `row x col x channel` while from matlab the image comes in blocks `rows x cols x channel_1` (after you transpose the image since matlab is column major). My question though now is whether I can do the same with `memcpy()` or `std::copy()` where I can copy the bloc data to contiguous form so that I bypass the `for` loop.